# AngularJs error in return value from filter function

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-util

I would like to filter a Firebase path and see if a child exist in my path.
I just want to return the values wich have a path call "reponses". It works but when the path doesn't have this Child, it throw me this error :

```
    firebase.js:283 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$value' of 
    firebase.js:276 FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback.
    TypeError: Cannot read property '$value' of undefined
```

I use Firebase-util and Angularfire like that :

```
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();

    var nc = new firebase.util.NormalizedCollection(
    ref.child('accounts/' + $localStorage.accountId + '/demandes'),
    [ref.child('demandes'), 'widget2']).select('widget2.duree', 'widget2.derniere_modification', 'widget2.reponses', 'widget2.exp', 'widget2.ajout_le', 'widget2.localisation').
    filter(function(data, key, priority) {
      return  data.reponses.$value !== null; // This cause problems !
    }).ref();
    $scope.items = $firebaseArray(nc);
```

**How can I do to test in a proper way other than `return  data.reponses.$value !== null;` ? Thank you**

Comment: Why not also check for the existence of the children and return (data.responses && data.responses.$value !== null)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like `data.responses` is `undefined` so you could check for `$value` like this:

```
.filter(function (data, key, priority) {
    return data.responses && data.responses.$value !== null;
}).ref();
```

This makes sure that there is a `responses` field on `data` before you probe it for `$value`.

Comment: The second solution still throws me back the same error but the first one do the job, thank you for your answer @Zach

Comment: I can't upvote this answer until you remove the second code portion. Your first code block is what I suggested in the comments and should work fine. However, in your second example, returning bool && string will more often than not yield results that are not intuitive. See docs on logical operators here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators